# Pass function component context as parameter in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I'm using `notistack` which has a simple usage:

```
const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();
enqueueSnackbar('text')
```

This needs to run inside a function component as `useSnackbar` is a hook itself.

I want to create a simple interface around it and export functions to use inside a function component:

```
import { useSnackbar } from 'notistack';

const toast = function () {
  const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();
  enqueueSnackbar(arguments)
}
const toastOptions = {
  anchorOrigin: {
    vertical: 'top',
    horizontal: 'right',
  }
}
const alert = (text) => toast(text, { variant: 'alert', ...toastOptions });
const warn = (text) => toast(text, { variant: 'warning', ...toastOptions });
const info = (text) => toast(text, { variant: 'info', ...toastOptions });
const success = (text) => toast(text, { variant: 'success', ...toastOptions });

export { alert, warn, info, success }
```

but this fails because `Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component`

Is there a way to pass the function component context as parameter? Tried to pass `this` and try to `this.call(toast...)` or similar, but `this` is undefined within a function component.

Comment: You can add a second param enqueueSnackbar in your functions alert, warn, info, success, and inside your components call your hook useSnackbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can surpass the problem of `Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component` by using useSnackbar  inside a custom hook:

```
import { useSnackbar } from "notistack";

const toastOptions = {
  anchorOrigin: {
    vertical: "top",
    horizontal: "right"
  }
};

export function useToast() {
  const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();
    
  const alert = (text) => enqueueSnackbar(text, { variant: "alert", ...toastOptions });
  const warn = (text) => enqueueSnackbar(text, { variant: "warning", ...toastOptions });
  const info = (text) => enqueueSnackbar(text, { variant: "info", ...toastOptions });
  const success = (text) =>
    enqueueSnackbar(text, { variant: "success", ...toastOptions });

  return { alert, warn, info, success };
}
```

Inside your component:

```
export const MyComponent () => {
   const { alert, warn, info, success } = useToast()
   //......
};
```